# Use prototype to call different functions so as to start and stop a process

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I am trying to have a function that I can get to start and stop by using prototypes.  My code:

```
function magnifyGlass(){}

magnifyGlass.prototype.begin=function(){

    $("#map_canvas").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#magnifyglass").show();
        magBox();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $("#magnifyglass").hide(); 
    });
}

magnifyGlass.prototype.end=function(){
    $("#magnifyglass").hide();
    $("#map_canvas").unbind();
}
```

My goal is to be able to call `magnifyGlass.begin()` and the div `magnifyglass` will show up and start doing things according to `magBox()` (FYI, it's a div that moves around a map).  Then if I call `magnifyGlass.end()`, the process will in effect turn off.  At this point `magBox` is fine, so I can get the thing to work if I stay away from this idea of using prototypes.  But if try to call `magnifyGlass.begin()`, I get the error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'magnifyGlass.begin()')`.  Any advise on how to learn how to do this would be greatly appreciated; I've been digging through examples and tutorials on the web for prototypes for hours now, and still can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do here is you create a "class". You need to instanciate it using the `new` operator.

So you would do

```
var mg = new magnifyGlass();
mg.begin();
```

Note that the convention is to start class names with uppercase (i.e. `MagnifyGlass`).

I'd suggest the [MDN introduction on OOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) to go further.

Comment: Thanks; that is exactly what I am trying to do, learn how to properly use objects instead of thinking in terms of procedures.